# Listing all files in a dropbox folder in R (so they can be read in)

Tags: r, database, dropbox, dropbox-api

Suppose I have a dropbox folder with several files in it.

For example:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rgiolfumqlhm9ng/AACs8AwiDmU98JR9UFm842-Ba?dl=0

How can I use R to list.files() in this folder?  This is necessary to get the sub-url locations to then read them in.

I've seen how to do this in python with API but I am working in R.

Comment: googling "R dropbox API" gets me to https://github.com/karthik/rdrop2 . Have you tried it?

Comment: Yep, what if the dropbox is someone elses and you just have the link though?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't looked at the package carefully at all. I'm just suggesting that you could do a bit more research/tell us what you've tried so far ... the package README says "... and the ability to upload and download files from any Dropbox account ..." which suggests that you might not need to own the files?

Comment: "Any" seems to be with the caveat that you own it.  I've pretty much read all of the documentation on stack and there's no question like this.  Additionally I have supplied a test dropbox link for expected output and reproducibility.  Any suggestions on how to improve the question further are appreciated. I think this would be useful to many people and am surprised to not see it up here yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use the API provided in the link, but then have the original owner authenticate a token for you. Once you have this token file, you can get into the dropbox with R.   The rest is straightforward from the link.